# ImportError: DLL load failed, with import sklearn

Tags: python, dll, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I made a program using scikit-learn, it was working fine for months. Yesterday, when I run it again it showed me the error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

I searched for an answer on StackOverflow and other websites. I also checked for the [requirements](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

I am using PyCharm Community edition 2019.2.1, 64 bit. 
my libraries status:-

joblib==0.14.0

numpy==1.17.2

pandas==0.25.1

scikit-learn==0.21.3

scipy==1.3.1

python==3.7.4, 32 bit

Error in the line:- 
     `import sklearn`

Comment: Where do you get your packages? Through Anaconda? If so, try creating a new environment with nothing but the given packages.

Comment: @fuglede I get my package directly using PyCharm installation in the virtual environment.